# ignore malformed XML with Perl-XML

Tags: html, xml, perl, html-parsing, xml-parsing

I'm using the perl command line utility xpath to extract data from some HTML code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $HTML | xpath -q -e "//h2[1]"
```

The HTML is malformed which causes xpath to throw the below error:

```
not well-formed (invalid token) at line X, column Y, byte Z:
```

I can't really fix the HTML since it's provided by an external source which means every time the HTML is changed I would have to fix it manually again.

I looked for xpath man which is pretty empty:
http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/xpath.1p/

I was wondering whether there would be a way to tell xpath to ignore the malformed HTML. To give you an idea of how malformed it is here are few lines from the source code:

```
<div id="header-background" style="top: 42px; >&nbsp;</div> <---- missing closing "
<div id-"page-inner">   <---- - instead of =
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) which uses an HTML parser to build a document which can then be queried using xpaths. An HTML Parser should be ok with malformed XML.

Also see this article on [HTML Scraping with XPath](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col92.html).

Comment: If possible I would rather like to use a command I can pipe the HTML into (like xpath) as the whole thing I inherited from is a bash script where content is retrieved/sent using curl.

Comment: You can make your Perl script behave this way .. see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138649/programmatically-read-from-stdin-or-input-file-in-perl

Comment: HTML is not XML so (AFAIK) you can't just expect a XML parser to read HTML, thats why you need something like HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Answer (score 4):

`xml_grep`, a command line tool which comes with XML::Twig, can be used to extract data from HTML using XPath. Normally it works on XML, but you can use the `-html` option to process HTML (under the hood it uses HTML::TreeBuilder to convert the XML to HTML).

For example:

```
> xml_grep -html -t 'a[@class="genu"]' http://stackoverflow.com
> Stack Exchange
```

Comment: well I tested with xml_grep -html and I'm getting the exact same error as with xpath

Comment: it looks like you've found a case where the conversion from HTML to XML doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to grab the development version of XML::Twig from http://mirod.org/xmltwig/ and you install HTML::Tidy, then you could use the new -Tidy option. Hopefully HTML::Tidy will do a better job with the conversion. Which now that I am awake and actually read your question will not help you that much as h2[1] is not supported :--( You could use HTML::Tidy to convert the HTML to XML though have a look at _tidy_html in the source of XML::Twig (in Twig.pm)