# How to get remote branch name in git pre-push hook

Tags: git, git-branch, githooks

The documentation says:

> Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook's
>   standard input with lines of the form:
>
> < local ref> SP < local sha1> SP < remote ref> SP < remote sha1> LF
>
> For instance, if the command +git push origin master:foreign+ were run
>   the hook would receive a line like the following:
>
> refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345

how do I access those lines in the pr-hook script?

Comment: You read the data from the hook's standard input stream. Any further explanation would require knowledge about what language the hook is written in.

Comment: Its in perl. And it's running on windows platform

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138649/programmatically-read-from-stdin-or-input-file-in-perl

Comment: Here is how it is done (I can't post an answer because I'm a new user so I will leave it here in the comments):

while read localref_ localsha1_ remoteref_ remotesha1_ 
do 
  echo $localref_ 
  echo $localsha1_ 
  echo $remoteref_ 
  echo $remotesha1_ 
done

Answer (score 5):

Remote branch name can be accessed using:

```
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha 
do 
    echo $local_ref
    echo $local_sha 
    echo $remote_ref
    echo $remote_sha
done
```

Comment: in v2.21.0 this doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to push not only one branch at once. You need to read:

1. **ARGV** in hook providing remote name ("often origin")
2. **STDIN** that is providing list of branches in format:

   local_branch_name from_commit remote_branch_name to_commit