# Perl module File:Slurp with STDIN piped

Tags: bash, perl, stdin

I have just tried using the following Perl script to do some text substitution using the File::Slurp module.  It works fine on a single file given as an argument at the command line (BASH).

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl -w

use File::Slurp qw( edit_file_lines );

foreach my $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV) {
  edit_file_lines { 
    s/foo/bar/g; 
    print $_
  } 
  $ARGV[$argnum];
}
```

I would like to alter it to cope also with pipes (i.e. STDIN), so that it can be in the middle of a series of piped operations:
for example:

`command blah|....|my-perl-script|sort|uniq|wc....`

What is the best way to change the Perl script to allow this, whilst retaining the existing ability to work with single files on the command line?

Comment: yes, but nothing I found addressed my specific question. the constraint of using File::Slurp module exclude answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138649/programmatically-read-from-stdin-or-input-file-in-perl?rq=1

Comment: [`edit_file_lines` is ... equivalent of the `-pi` command line options of Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#edit_file,-edit_file_lines). Do you not understand what `-pi` does or is there some additional reason that you have to use `File::Slurp` for this task?

Comment: I've edited your question to add indentation to your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself next time. If you're asking a large group of people to read and understand your code, then surely it's only polite to make it as easy to follow as possible.

Comment: I recommend against using File::Slurp. It has huge issues and it doesn't look like they're going to be fixed any time soon (e.g. https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83126 - encodings are completely broken).

Comment: @mob, yes, I had been using  commandline perl -pi, but increasing complexity made me want to learn how to do it in a proper perl script.  The example I gave was only a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your script work in a pipeline, you could check if `STDIN` is connected to a `tty`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw( edit_file_lines );

sub my_edit_func {  s/foo/bar/g;  print $_ }

if ( !(-t STDIN) ) {
    while(<>) { my_edit_func }
}
else {
    foreach my $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV) {
        edit_file_lines { my_edit_func } $ARGV[$argnum];
    }
}
```

See [`perldoc -X`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for more information on the `-t` file test operator.

Comment: This answers the question because it allows me to use the File::Slurp package (or, in general, others).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the following:

```
local $^I = '';

while (<>) {
  s/foo/bar/g; 
  print;
}
```

This is basically the same as `perl -i -pe's/foo/bar/'`, except it doesn't warn when STDIN is used.

Comment: I know about this construct, my question required using the File::Slurp package.  But comment from  @melpomene makes me think I might need to steer away from that package.